# SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient is not working

Tags: c#, https, x509certificate2, sslstream

I'm trying to connect to an https server using the SslStream class (the server uses a trusted root certificate), but when i use the SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String, X509CertificateCollection, SslProtocols, Boolean), the program stands there infinitely without throwing any exception or going on.
Here is the code:

```
String serverName = "https://192.168.32.74/params.cgi";
String pfxName = @"C:\...\server.pfx";

X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(pfxName, "mypassword");
//Create new X509 store called teststore from the local certificate store.
X509Store store = new X509Store("teststore", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

//Create a collection and add two of the certificates.
X509Certificate2Collection collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
collection.Add(certificate);

store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
store.AddRange(collection);
try
{
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        client.Connect(server, port);
        SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(
            client.GetStream(),
            false,
            new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate),
            null);

        sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(
            serverName,
            collection,
            SslProtocols.Default,
            true);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex.ToString());
}
...
```

Does anyone know why i am having this issue?

**Update:**

I have updated the code with the .pfx file

Answer (score 1):

Because you are trying to perform client certificate authentication without private key (in the `cerName` variable. You should reference the X509Certificate2 object with valid private key. Either, from PKCS#12/PFX file or from personal store.

---

## Update:

You need to merge your `server.crt` and `server.key` into PFX file. Place both files in the same folder (and make sure both names have the same name) and run certutil command:

```
certutil -mergepfx path\server.crt path\server.pfx
```

where `path\server.crt` is actual path to .crt file and `path\server.pfx` is the path where to save resulting PFX. When prompted, enter password for PFX. Then use [X509Certificate2 (String, SecureString)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148419(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor to get the certificate with private key in your code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have the server.key file that contains the private key, how should i add that to my code to make the certificate work? (i'm new to c# and i'm still learning, so maybe i miss something)

Comment: As you suggest, i created the server.pfx file and replaced it in the code, as you can see from the updated code, but i still have the same issue.